# Get value from Vue component in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get a value easily from a component in Laravel blade,

```js
<input name="avatar" type="hidden" :value="$refs.webcam.img" />
<webcam-avatar ref="webcam"></webcam-avatar>
```

I know this is wrong I just don't have sufficient knowledge in Vue, this is how I tried to show that I need back an image from the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your vue components define watcher and emit event on webcam value change :

```
  watch: {
    webcam: function (val) {
      this.$emit('webcamchange',val)
    }
  }
```

then handle event on your main page:

```
<input name="avatar" type="hidden" :value="webcam.img" />
<webcam-avatar @webcamchange="webcam"></webcam-avatar>
```

don't forgot to define webcam on data section in your main page :

```
   data:function () {
    return {
      webcam:{}
      }
    }
```